# Paperjs firing resize event

Tags: paperjs

I am trying to fire resize event but I got: TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

My code is:

```
onResize = function (event){

    view.viewSize = [event.size.width, 35]

    }


view.fire('resize');
```

What is  wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

view.fire('resize', view);

We have to pass the event object to the fire function too.